# Java: MYSQL ResultSet not getting values

Tags: java, mysql

I have a method, which simply return a string value. It is first required to connect to a mysql database @ db4free.net (I have check and made sure that there are no problems whilst connecting). Then there is a `PreparedStatement` In which the query `SELECT * FROM ip` is executed. ResultSet stores the query result but when I do result.getString(1) it returns nothing. Here's my code below (The class Client extends Connector btw)

```
public String ObtainServerIP(){
    if(MYSQLConnection!=null){
        try{
            PreparedStatement state = MYSQLConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM "+TableName);
            result = state.executeQuery();
            result.next();
            return result.getString(1);
        }catch(Exception e){
            return ""+e;
        }
    }
    return "wot m8";
}
```

The code above is in the Connector class.

The code below is what needs to print the stuff out. (I've even tried index 0 on result set, still nothing).

```
public void run(){
    while(AppRunning){
        if(DatabaseConnection){
            System.out.println(ObtainServerIP());
            AppRunning=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes the loop is working fine, DatabaseConnection is true and the loop makes it ways into the if statement. However nothing print's out. Even an exception isn't being printed out. Here's a snapshot from my MYSQL Database:

[image]

Comment: what output are you getting? use column name to make it clear what column you want to fetch from result set.

Comment: @Braj Nothing really. Except for the "connected" output from another method to make sure the connection is fine.

Comment: debug the code and add some more SOP and look where it breaks.

Comment: Wait..hwow do I open the debug perspective again...

Comment: @Braj the debugger shows nothing. It works just fine, the code isn't breaking.

Comment: [1] check if the table queried is really ip [2] check if you're accessing the right db [3] check if you're trying to select data that was inserted AND committed

Comment: Just guessing: TableName is not 'ip'. Try 'MYSQLConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ip")'; to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better create a String before if statement and the parameter for getString must be the attribute of the table. If you want to obtain only 1 row use if statement for result.next(), in other case use while. Try this:

```
public String ObtainServerIP(){
String text;

if(MYSQLConnection!=null){
    try{
        PreparedStatement state = MYSQLConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM "+TableName);
        result = state.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            text = result.getString("InternetProtocol");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        text = e.getMessage();
    }
}
return text;
```

}